# How is HashSet's iterator implemented in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

I am interested in Java's implementation of HashSet's iterator method, could some one paste the core code here please? Thanks.

Comment: Please Check the link for source code of hashset http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Program Files and look for the java folder all the classes are zipped in the src.zip located in the directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

Note:- Depending on your version of java the jdk file name may be different and also the Program Files directory could be the x86 one depending on your java installation.

incase if you have problems finding it, here is the entire class taken from jdk1.8.0_65 http://pastebin.com/zzpfN7HY

Another way would be to ctrl + click on the HashSet code to open up the declaration in your IDE